# Splunk searching event logs to find values exceeding a given threshold

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to search the log event

```
"Closure request counts: startAssets: "
```

and find occurrences where the `startAssets` are larger than 50.

How would I do that?

Something like:

```
Closure request counts: startAssets: 51
```

would maybe give a search similar to

```
"Closure request counts: startAssets: {num} AND num >=50"
```

perhaps?

What does that look like in SPL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty simple, but you'll need to extract the number to do it.  I like to use the `rex` command to do that, but there may be other ways.

```
index=foo "Closure request counts: startAssets: *"
| rex "startAssets: (?<startAssets>\d+)"
| where startAssets > 50
```